# redefine symbols for arm64 macOS

Tags: c++, arm64, objcopy

I have two static third-party libraries which have same exported symbol, and all of symbols I what to use in my shared library.
[objcopy](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/objcopy.html) can redefine symbols from library. After install binutils package from [brew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/binutils), extract all *.o files from static library and call objcopy for each *.o files

```
objcopy --redefine-sym
```

pack objects with

```
ar r *.o
```

and

```
ranlib mylib.a
```

but when I try to compile dymamic library linker show warning:

```
mylib.a, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-unsupported file format ( 0x21 0x3C 0x61 0x72 0x63 0x68 0x3E 0x0A 0x23 0x31 0x2F 0x32 0x30 0x20 0x20 0x20
```

If use objcopy with  --output-target mach-o-arm64, linker warning transform to

```
mylib.a, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for iOS-arm64
```

It work for x86_64 libraries, but fiasco for arm64..

Comment: I think you want `llvm-objcopy`, not GNU `objcopy`.

Comment: mach-o-arm64 is unsupported by [llvm-objcopy](https://llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/llvm-objcopy.html)

Comment: The clang documentation is enigmatic and virtually always incomplete. Just download [clang 12](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/releases/tag/llvmorg-12.0.0), run `llvm-objcopy --redefine-sym=_old=_new in.o out.o` and you'll see that it works.

Comment: This might require a newer version of llvm at this point, can you try by building yourself? At least simple cases work on my machine with llvm @ HEAD